# pdfkit how to detect end of page to addpage in loop over collection in meteor js

Tags: meteor, pdfkit

In pdfkit how to generate page only if previous page is full (blank part shoul first fill then generate new page) inside some loop over array of object from mongodb.

[image: Example Scenario]

Answer (score 4):

What I do when using pdfkit is draw all visual elements using a variable for the vertical position called `ypos`, which I increment as I move down a page, e.g. `ypos += 20;`. Let's say I'm using `var doc = new PDFDocument({size: 'A4', margin: 20});` , then at moments where there might be risk of the text flowing beyond a page border I check how far ypos has been incremented. `if (ypos > 680){ doc.addPage(); ypos = 50; }` .

However, an issue arises when you draw something and are unsure how high it might be, and whether it flows beyond the page border at the current `ypos` of the page. One of the things that you could do (this is sort of a nasty solution) is to draw the text in white (so it's drawn but invisible), and then check the value of `doc.y`, which shows you at which vertical location pdfkit has last drawn. If it's too far down, create a new page and draw there, if not, stay on the page where you are.

Comment: How do you know the increment for `ypos`?

Comment: I guess that depends entirely on the font-size you're using and the spacing that you want between visual elements. I always just experiment a little with different values untill the spacing is just right. Not sure if that answers your question. (:

Comment: Yes. I thought that maybe there were some rules to know it, but ok anyway.